# Remove Top Line of Text File with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to just remove the first line of about 5000 text files before importing them.

I am still very new to PowerShell so not sure what to search for or how to approach this. My current concept using pseudo-code:

```
set-content file (get-content unless line contains amount)
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do something like contains.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is not the most efficient in the world, but this should work:

```
get-content $file |
    select -Skip 1 |
    set-content "$file-temp"
move "$file-temp" $file -Force
```

Comment: When I try to run this it seems that it errors out on the -skip. Could that maybe be from a different version?

Comment: -Skip is new to Select-Object in PowerShell 2.0.  Also, if the files are all ascii then you might want to use set-content -enc ascii.  If the encodings are mixed, then it gets trickier unless you don't care about the file encoding.

Answer (score 58):

While I really admire the answer from @hoge both for a very concise technique and a wrapper function to generalize it and I encourage upvotes for it, I am compelled to comment on the other two answers that use temp files (it gnaws at me like fingernails on a chalkboard!).

Assuming the file is not huge, you can force the pipeline to operate in discrete sections--thereby obviating the need for a temp file--with judicious use of parentheses:

```
(Get-Content $file | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $file
```

... or in short form:

```
(gc $file | select -Skip 1) | sc $file
```

Answer (score 13):

Using variable notation, you can do it without a temporary file:

```
${C:\file.txt} = ${C:\file.txt} | select -skip 1

function Remove-Topline ( [string[]]$path, [int]$skip=1 ) {
  if ( -not (Test-Path $path -PathType Leaf) ) {
    throw "invalid filename"
  }

  ls $path |
    % { iex "`${$($_.fullname)} = `${$($_.fullname)} | select -skip $skip" }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I just had to do the same task, and `gc | select ... | sc` took over 4 GB of RAM on my machine while reading a 1.6 GB file. It didn't finish for at least 20 minutes after reading the whole file in (as reported by Read Bytes in [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer)), at which point I had to kill it.

My solution was to use a more .NET approach: `StreamReader` + `StreamWriter`.
See this answer for a great answer discussing the perf: *[In Powershell, what's the most efficient way to split a large text file by record type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159763/in-powershell-whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-split-a-large-text-file-by-recor)*

Below is my solution. Yes, it uses a temporary file, but in my case, it didn't matter (it was a freaking huge SQL table creation and insert statements file):

```
PS> (measure-command{
    $i = 0
    $ins = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader "in/file/pa.th"
    $outs = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "out/file/pa.th"
    while( !$ins.EndOfStream ) {
        $line = $ins.ReadLine();
        if( $i -ne 0 ) {
            $outs.WriteLine($line);
        }
        $i = $i+1;
    }
    $outs.Close();
    $ins.Close();
}).TotalSeconds
```

It returned:

```
188.1224443
```

Comment: IIRC this is because the parentheses around the gc|select means it reads the entire file into memory before piping it through. Otherwise the open stream causes set-content to fail. For big files I think your approach is probably best

Comment: Thank you, @AASoft, for your great solution! I've allowed myself to improve it slightly by dropping the comparison operation in every loop speeding up the process by something like 25% - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24746158/177710) for details.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [AASoft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751861/177710), I went out to improve it a bit more:

1. **Avoid** the loop variable `$i` and **the comparison** with `0` in every loop
2. Wrap the execution into a `try..finally` block to always close the files in use
3. Make the solution work for an **arbitrary number of lines to remove** from the beginning of the file
4. Use a variable `$p` to reference the current directory

These changes lead to the following code:

```
$p = (Get-Location).Path

(Measure-Command {
    # Number of lines to skip
    $skip = 1
    $ins = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader ($p + "\test.log")
    $outs = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter ($p + "\test-1.log")
    try {
        # Skip the first N lines, but allow for fewer than N, as well
        for( $s = 1; $s -le $skip -and !$ins.EndOfStream; $s++ ) {
            $ins.ReadLine()
        }
        while( !$ins.EndOfStream ) {
            $outs.WriteLine( $ins.ReadLine() )
        }
    }
    finally {
        $outs.Close()
        $ins.Close()
    }
}).TotalSeconds
```

The first change brought the processing time for my 60 MB file down from `5.3s` to `4s`. The rest of the changes is more cosmetic.

Comment: You may want to add `-and !$ins.EndOfStream` to the `for` loop conditional to cover the cases where the file has fewer lines than `$skip`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! That makes sense :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$x = get-content $file
$x[1..$x.count] | set-content $file
```

Just that much. Long boring explanation follows. Get-content returns an array. We can "index into" array variables, as demonstrated in [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/06/add-modify-verify-and-sort-your-powershell-array.aspx) and [other](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692791.aspx) Scripting Guys posts.

For example, if we define an array variable like this,

```
$array = @("first item","second item","third item")
```

so $array returns

```
first item
second item
third item
```

then we can "index into" that array to retrieve only its 1st element

```
$array[0]
```

or only its 2nd

```
$array[1]
```

or a [range](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) of index values from the 2nd through the last.

```
$array[1..$array.count]
```

Answer (score 4):

I just learned from a website:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | ForEach-Object { (get-Content $_) | Where-Object {(1) -notcontains $_.ReadCount } | Set-Content -path $_ }
```

Or you can use the aliases to make it short, like:

```
gci *.txt | % { (gc $_) | ? { (1) -notcontains $_.ReadCount } | sc -path $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. Could you indicate the website you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to remove the first line from file, using multiple assignment technique. Refer [Link](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/10/08/pstip-how-to-remove-the-first-line-from-a-text-file/)

```
 $firstLine, $restOfDocument = Get-Content -Path $filename 
 $modifiedContent = $restOfDocument 
 $modifiedContent | Out-String | Set-Content $filename
```

Answer (score 1):

skip` didn't work, so my workaround is

```
$LinesCount = $(get-content $file).Count
get-content $file |
    select -Last $($LinesCount-1) | 
    set-content "$file-temp"
move "$file-temp" $file -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [Michael Soren's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236944/19329554) answer.

If you want to edit all .txt files in the current directory and remove the first line from each.

```
Get-ChildItem (Get-Location).Path -Filter *.txt | 
Foreach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For smaller files you could use this:

& C:\windows\system32\more +1 oldfile.csv > newfile.csv | out-null

... but it's not very effective at processing my example file of 16MB. It doesn't seem to terminate and release the lock on newfile.csv.