# Command Line Script to Delete Header Row from a number of TXT files

Tags: batch-file, shell, windows-scripting

What's the best method to delete the first line of text from a large (10k+) group of text files.

Answer (score 3):

If PowerShell isn't an option, you can use the `more` command:

```
more [file] +2 > [new file]
```

Stick that in a `for` loop that also then renames `[new file]` to `[file]` and you'll have the file minus the first line.

Not pretty, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install [TAIL](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) in your sistem

```
tail -n +2 filename > finalfilename
```

shows all the filename except the first line.

The windows CMD, in my opinion, isn't the best "terminal". However, you don't need `tail` command. As Patrick Cuff said, you cand use the `more` command that does basically the same.

I think that is the best answer to do with buil-in commands.

If you know a bit about programming, you can make a small program that does what you want and call it in a bat file.

Also, you can use other windows terminals like [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) or [console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) that have more flexible built in commands to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: Installing via cygwin would gain you many such tools. for i in files ; do tail -n +2 $i > $i_noheader ; done

Comment: Yeah, but the answer of Patric Cuff is basically the same and is built-in in windows :P. And If you want to install some new shell, I think some people prefer installing PowerShell or Console instead of Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

If using PowerShell is an option you could adopt from this post: [Remove Top Line of Text File with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

download [sed for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). Then do this

```
c:\test> sed -i.bak "1d" file
```

use a for loop to iterate files