# Remove top line of a huge (300M) text file with powershell

Tags: powershell, file-io

The difference between this question and [Remove Top Line of Text File with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell) is that my file is huge (over 300M).

The technique I am using now is based on [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076557/80002) to that question, however it seems inefficient for huge files. Is there a faster (and less pretty) way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a streamreader and streamwriter. This should perform quickly.

```
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText("C:\Users\Andy\Documents\input.txt")
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Andy\Documents\output.txt")

$reader.ReadLine() > $null # Skip first line.
while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $writer.writeline($reader.ReadLine())
}

$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

I tested by creating a 300MB text file and used this on it. output.txt was created in 3.5 seconds :-).

*Update* I optimized it slightly so it doesn't doesn't evaluate an expression every iteration of the loop. Now it completes in 2.9 seconds :-)

If you don't mind memory bloat you can also do this. This is faster still but takes more memory, but less than `Get-Content`.

```
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText("C:\Users\Andy\Documents\input.txt")
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Andy\Documents\output.txt")

$reader.ReadLine() > $null # Skip first line.
$writer.write($reader.ReadToEnd())

$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As in Andy's answer, a StreamWriter is the way to go.
However, I saw better results from `Measure-Command` using `gc $file -ReadCount 0` than a StreamReader.

```
$contents=gc C:\My\File.txt -ReadCount 0
$w=New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\My\File.txt")
foreach($line in $contents){if(!$f++){continue}$w.WriteLine($line)}
```

This also has the added benefit of being able to read from and write to the same file.

Comment: `ReadCount` 0 will load everything into memory which bloats up PowerShell quite a bit. It ran up to 720MBs for me. Depending how much memory is available it could cause an out of memory exception.

Comment: Yes, no doubt it will bump up memory usage. In large files I've experimented with before PowerShell will grow over 3x the file size (which is a question I'd like to know the answer to on it's own), but with a file that size I assumed it was a server environment, which would've implied it had plenty of resources and preferred performance.