# Remove Extra Lines from CSV

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I have CSV file that I am trying to remove extra lines (not sure how many lines it will be) from top of CSV, and then lines in the middle of the CSV that say SourceIP, DestinationIP, etc

[image]

I tried the following:

```
$m = gc D:\Script\textfile.txt
Select-String D:\Script\my.csv -pattern $m -Match
```

And textfile.text has

```
*.*.*.*
```

But I get error,

```
Select-String : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Match'.
```

How do I even match the strings I want (or don't want), because I'd like the resulting CSV to be

[image]

Comment: If you're just removing the top 7 lines, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I'm not sure if it will be 7 lines, or more, hence I need a uniform approach

Comment: That is pretty important information and you need to add it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Import-Csv` cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv YourFileLocation -Header SourceIP, DestinationIP, Application |
     where {$_.SourceIP -match "^[0-9]+"} | Export-Csv OutputFile.csv
```

It allows you to set custom header names, and then you can do regex search through `SourceIP` header, and take **only** stuff that starts with digit. If that's done,  you can use Export-Csv to spit it out.

Comment: And you fixed what I was about to ask with `^`