# How to Use While loop in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using the variable $listing as the file name as given below.

```
Get-Content BHS_output.txt | Select-String -pattern $listing| sort | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$listing", ""} > $listing
```

Where `$listing` is the variable from the first row of the file on first iteration. On the second iteration

```
$listing = Get-Content .\file.txt | select-object -First 1 .
```

`$listing` must have BHS_E_CNBY20150622035126.CSV .. Not BHS_E_BHSA20150622035126.CSV .

File name : TestFile1_sorted.txt

```
BHS_E_BHAA20150622035126.CSV
BHS_E_BHSA20150622035126.CSV
BHS_E_CNBY20150622035126.CSV
BHS_E_PACS20150622035126.CSV
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Top Line of Text File with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell)

Comment: In case it is related can you show us what you mean by _I need to use the output file inside the while loop statement for more than 5 times_

Comment: I was using the variable $listing as the file name as below.                Get-Content BHS_output.txt | Select-String -pattern $listing| sort | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$listing", ""} > $listing                                        Where $listing is the variable from the first row of the file on first iteration. On the second iteration $listing = Get-Content .\file.txt |  select-object -First 1 .  $listing must have BHS_E_CNBY20150622035126.CSV .. Not BHS_E_BHSA20150622035126.CSV.

Comment: So i need to delete the first row from the file TestFile1_sorted.txt to proceed furthur..   I'm woking as a Sybase developer and this was my first project. Thanks in Advance Matt.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with that information. Your question possible different then your title suggests.

Comment: Sorry but you made this question really unclear to me. Where is the while loop? Why are you using `select-string`. Do you need the first line saved? How many files are you working on?

Answer (score 1):

The error you would be getting would be about saving to the same file you are reading from which is the product of the pipeline you created. Each line is processed one at a time so the second line is being written to file while the files is still open to keep reading.

```
(Get-Content $path) | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $path
```

Putting the `(Get-Content $path)` in brackets will process the entire file into memory. Beware if the file is large. Then the rest of your code will work as normally.

Comment: If both the path of Get-content and Set-content is same, Will it work? For me its throwing error as Unable to Open the document.

Comment: @JohnChristopher Yes this _exact_ code will work assuming that the file is not already open and that you have the right permissions in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just "select" instead of "select-object"

```
Get-Content TestFile1_sorted.txt | Select -Skip 1
```

Someone answered a question about this before:
[Remove Top Line of Text File with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074271/remove-top-line-of-text-file-with-powershell)

```
get-content $file |
    select -Skip 1 |
    set-content "$file-temp"
move "$file-temp" $file -Force
```

Comment: `Select` is the same as `Select-Object` one is an alias of the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$a = Get-Content C:\temp.txt
$a[1..-1] | Out-File c:\newfile.txt
```

if you want to overwrite the file replace the destination

what it does it creates new array and select it from the 2nd to the end

Comment: I want to use it inside the while loop Statement.So there should not be destination Folder in it.